# Type Scripit # Always getting Array of zero size

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mean-stack, angular2-services

I am trying to use the following code to get the value of all spams in `Home.ts` from my `Auth.service`  method `getSpams()` which is running fine and giving results correctly in console. But when I am trying to save the result of service in `Object(totalspam)` of `Home.ts`  its giving Array of zero size.

Following are the my components:

**Home.ts**

```
    import { NavController , IonicPage} from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth-service/auth-service';
    import { Spam } from '../../providers/auth-service/auth-service';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {

      totalspam:Spam[] = [];

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private auth:AuthService) {

         this.auth.getSpams().subscribe(spam=>{this.totalspam = spam});
         console.log(this.totalspam);

      }

    }
```

**AuthService.ts**

```
    getSpams(): Observable<Spam[]> {
              let url = 'http://115.113.49.148:8080/allspam';
              let headers = new Headers();
              headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
              let options   = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

              // get spams from api
              return this.http.get(url, options)
                  .map((response) => response.json());
          }
```

**AuthService.ts**

```
    export class Spam
    {
      _id:string;
      count:Number;
      spamNumber:string;
      spamType:Array<String>;  
    }
```

Comment: the results come asynchronously are you sure you're not just looking too early at the results? If the console.log in the constructor is what you are looking at, that's going to execute way before the result comes back from the server.

Comment: @tosky Strange thing is when I am writing this.auth.getSpams().subscribe(spam=>{console.log(spam);}) its printing problem with totalspams

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you're console logging results directly after an asynchronous method. This line: `console.log(this.totalspam);` is being called before the value has actually changed. When you're dealing with an asynchronous request, factors such as latency, size of request and the browser itself can mean variable resolve times.

The purpose of an asynchronous method is to run and deal with a result at a later time without blocking any other code, so `console.log` is invoked immediately. If you change your code to the following, provided you are getting a result back you should see the array populated:

```
this.auth.getSpams().subscribe(spam => {
    this.totalspam = spam;

    console.log(this.totalspam);
});
```

If you still do not see anything, then you should check whether or not your request is returning the desired results.

Comment: thanks its working fine i was confused as I am new into this second suggestion .I am from java background should i learn TS directly or go through JS first